# How put transform rows to column in SQL

Tags: sql, vertica

I have the following table

[image]

`EURtoUSD` column always shows the same value for all of the dates across the different groups in `car`.

How can I create the following table?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select date, eurtousd,
       max(case when car = 'Audi' then priceeur end) as audi,
       max(case when car = 'BMW' then priceeur end) as bmw,
       max(case when car = 'MB' then priceeur end) as mb
from t
group by date, eurtousd;
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you also help, if i.e. I want to again create the long table (1st table) from the wide table (2nd table), what should I use then?

Comment: @PriitMets . . . You can use `union all`.

Comment: It will make the query too long (in real case there are more cars). Is there something similar to UNPIVOT (Oracle) function?

Comment: I'm afraid Vertica does not have a pivot or unpivot function .. My usual workaround is to use SQL generating SQL to , yes, generate a SQL statement that does the pivoting.